# multidimensional complex valued array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have to generate a multidimensional array `N (j, k, m, l)`  which is complex valued, approximately 10*100*100*1000.

I want to do the following to compute this N and return.

```
for j<10 ...
{
  for k<100 ...
  {
     ......
     some matrix multiplication to generate a 2D complex valued matrix n(100*1000)
     ......
     N(j,k,:,:)= n
   }
}
```

My questions:

1. how to implement `N(j,k,:,:)= n` efficiently.
2. for the present problem size, should I code from scratch or use some existing library?

Comment: What is `lhs' and `rhs` you're talking about?

Comment: @MariusBancila I mean size of N and n are not the same

Comment: There are some C++ library's which can help you with matrixes: [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: 10*100*100*1000 complex valued array -- that's rather huge. Are you sure this is what you truly need?

Comment: If this is a double array, one such N requires 800,000,000. Any other biggies in your program? - Is the 10x100 matrix densely populated with theses 100x1000 elements? Are the 100x1000 matrices densely populated? - Consider using std::array which will let you assign arrays using `=`.

Comment: @DavidHammen I don't think it's "complex" as opposed to "real", just "more complex than a simple scalar" ;-)

Comment: Obligatory boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: @laune  yeah, they are dense matrix.

Comment: If it is fixed sized, just use `std::array<std::array<std::array<std::array<Complex, N>,M>,K>,J> arr` and `std::array<std::array<Complex,N>,M> n`, and do copy use `std::copy(n.begin(), n.end(), arr[j][k])`. If you are using C++11, use `std::vector` and use move assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about 10*100*100*1000 = 100,000,000 complex numbers, likely 8 bytes each if 2 `float`s, or 16 bytes for 2 `doubles`, so roughly 800 megabytes or 1.6 gigabytes.  Well within the capacity of an average desktop PC, which is a good start.

The main thing for efficient assignment is to ensure the memory layout is such that the assignment is dealing with contiguous memory.  You can write a couple classes to provide a nice interface - say `Matrix_2D` then a `Matrix_4D` like:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix_4D
{
  public:
    Matrix_4D(size_t j, size_t k, size_t l, size_t m)
      : j_(j), k_(k), l_(l), m_(m), data_(new T[j * k * l * m]),
        klm_(k * l * m), lm_(l * m),
    { /* optionally, initialise elements */ }

    ~Matrix_4D() { delete data_; }

    T& operator()(size_t j, size_t k, size_t l, size_t m)
    {
        return data_[j * klm_ + k * lm_ + l * m_ + m];
    }

    const T& operator()(size_t j, size_t k, size_t l, size_t m) const
    {
        return data_[j * klm_ + k * lm_ + l * m_ + m];
    }

    void set(size_t l, size_t m, const Matrix_2D& m2)
    {
        if (m2.j_ != l_ || m2.k_ != m_)
            throw std::runtime_error("mismatched dimensions");
        std::copy(m2.data_[0], m2.data_[lm_], (*this)(l, m, 0, 0));
    }

  private:
    size_t j_, k_, l_, m_;
    size_t klm_, lm_; // needed so often -> save
    T* data_;
};
```

The matrix classes should be `friend`s so they can rip data out of each other.  If you want to get fancier, you can actually provide a proxy object - add the following to `Matrix_4D`

```
    struct Proxy_2D
    {
        Proxy_2D(Matrix_4D& m4, size_t l, size_t m) : m4_(m4), l_(l), m_(m) { }
        Proxy_2D& operator=(const Matrix2D& m2)
        {
            m4_.set(l_, m_, m2);
            return *this;
        }
        Matrix_4D& m4_;
        size_t l_, m_;
    };

    Proxy_2D operator()(size_t l, size_t m) { return Proxy_2D(*this, l, m); }
```

Then you can do this:

```
Matrix_4D m4(10, 20, 30, 40);
Matrix_2D m2(30, 40);
... set stuff in m2 ...
m4(2, 4) = m2;
```

---

EDIT: for the code in your comment - `m2= m2 * transpose(m2)` - if you want to pursue this kind of do-it-yourself implementation to learn C++ rather than grab an existing efficient library using high-performance techniques like template expressions (which are way too complicated to get into here), then in `Matrix_2D`:

```
    Matrix_2D transpose() const
    {
        Matrix_2D result(m_, l_);
        for (size_t l = 0; l < l_; ++l)
            for (size_t m = 0; m < m_; ++m)
                result(m, l)= (*this)(l, m);
        return result;
    }

    Matrix_2D& operator+=(const Matrix_2D& rhs)
    {
        for (size_t l = 0; l < l_; ++l)
            for (size_t m = 0; m < m_; ++m)
                (*this)(l, m) += rhs(l, m);
        return *this;
    }

    Matrix_2D operator+(const Matrix_2D& rhs) const
    {
        Matrix_2D result(*this); // copy *this
        return result += rhs;
    }
```

Interestingly, you can also have a transpose as a kind of dynamic perspective on a matrix without copying the data, but then you need to make sure the underlying matrix object's lifetime spans the use of the transposition object:

```
template <typename T>
class Transpose_2D
{
  public:
    Transpose_2D(Matrix_2D<T>& m) : m_(m) { }

    T& operator()(size_t l, size_t m) { return m_(m, l); }
    const T& operator()(size_t l, size_t m) const { return m_(m, l); }

  private:
    Matrix_2D<T>& m_;
};
```

Changing the Matrix_2D addition function signatures correspondingly allows this to be used, e.g.:

```
template <typename U>
Matrix_2D& operator+=(const U& rhs)
...
```

Then you can do:

```
m2 += Transpose_2D(m2);
```

And it will be reasonably efficient.

Comment: You need to add `j_` ... as a member.'

Comment: @TonyD  a stupid question, when I set stuff in m2, am I free to use sth like m2= m2 * transpose(m2)? sorry a newbie here...

Comment: @lorniper: it will be easier to be efficient if you write a dedicated member function in Matrix_2D that multiplies the matrix by its transpose... then it can index to the elements directly without any extra memory for a temporary 2d array of the transpose of `m2`, then another temporary for `m2 * ` that temporary, only to the thrown away when the assignment is done.  Sophisticated C++ libraries for this kind of thing use "template expressions" to allow intuitive notation like `m2 = m2 * transpose(m2)` while being as efficient as possible: e.g. [blitz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blitz/)

Comment: @TonyD BTW, the extensive use of underscore '_' just indicates private member ?

Comment: @lorniper I use that for data members, regardless of access specified (i.e. public / protected / private )... probably a little less common than an m_ prefix, but I find it very readable.  And you're very welcome.  Cheers.